# Calculation within if statement under switch

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, calculation

I am trying to write code that allows a user to input a filing status and the income to calculate the tax owed. if filing status input is outside of 1-4 , program will exit. I'm trying to use the switch and if else if, but looks like I am stuck with the code generating the tax owed portion. whenever I input the income, it will not generate the tax owed amount. example, for case 1: in switch (last line) for filing status I input 1(for single) and input 20000 for income. the result should show $3000 but it will not give any result. below is the code I have so far.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

//declaration  status = filing status , income = income input, taxOwed = tax owed calculation.
int status;
double income, taxOwed;

//data/input
printf("************Menu****************\n");
printf("1) Single\n");
printf("2) Married Filing Jointly\n");
printf("3) Married Filing Separately\n");
printf("4) Head of Household\n");
printf("5) Exit\n");
printf("\n");
printf("********************************\n");
printf("\n");
printf("Enter status : ");
scanf("%d", &status);

//processing switch with Calculation within each case
switch(status)
{
    case 5:
        printf("\n", status);
        printf("Exit Program...\n");
        break;
    case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
        printf("You entered a wrong status. Program Exit . . .");
        break;
    default:
        printf("You entered a wrong status. Program Exit . . .");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Enter your taxable TI: $");
        scanf("%.2lf\n", income);
        if (0 < income <= 24000)
        {
            taxOwed = (income * 0.15);
            printf("\n");
            printf("The taxes owed are: $%.2lf", taxOwed);
            break;
        }
        else if (24000 < income <= 58000)
        {
            taxOwed = 3600 + (0.28 * (income - 24000));
            printf("The taxes owed are: $%.2lf", taxOwed);
            break;
        }

}

return 0;
}
```

any review and help is much appreciated. thank you

Comment: Regarding your previous edit: With `printf`, you can use the `%f` format specifier for both `float` and `double`, but with `scanf`, you must use `%lf` for double. This is because `float` gets promoted to `double` when calling a variadic function such as `printf`. No promotion of any kind occurs with `scanf`.

Comment: Do not edit the post to change the question being asked, e.g., by making some fixes in the code and asking what remains wrong. Stack Overflow is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers that other people can use as a reference. When you change the question, future readers no longer see a matched question-and-answer, so the answers do not tell them how to fix a particular problem. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service, and you should not use it that way. You should mostly debug your program yourself and ask one **specific** question at a time.

Comment: That means it is your responsibility to narrow down a problem to a specific part of the program and to ask a question only about that part, preferably extracting that specific section of code into a small program that demonstrates the problem you are having with it.

Comment: Since the follow-up question is settled now, it may be appropriate to delete it, in order to restore the original question.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i have deleted the 2nd question because it is settled, but 3rd follow up question still have issue and it does not print the string with taxOwed.

Comment: @NewB123: Your latest code works with me. When I enter `1` on the first line and `20000` on the second line, it gives `3000` as output. I tried it with the compilers gcc and clang and it works with both. `Enter status : 1<newline>Enter your taxable TI: $20000<newline>The taxes owed are: $3000.00`

Comment: @NewB123: You may want to change `printf("The taxes owed are: $%.2lf", taxOwed);` to `printf("The taxes owed are: $%.2lf\n", taxOwed);` (add a `\n` at the end of the format string). Maybe your operating system/IDE has trouble displaying partial lines. Also, the line `printf("\n", status);` might be causing trouble, because you are passing a parameter, although `printf` is not expecting one, because you did not mention one in the format string. You should change that line to `printf( "\n" );` (remove passing the value of `status`).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i recopied the code in a new project and tried it and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

`scanf("%.2lf\n", income);`

is wrong, for three reasons:

1. The function `scanf` expects the address of the variable it should write to, not the previous value of the variable.
2. It is unclear what the you intend the `.2` to do. You are probably confusing the `scanf` format string with the `printf` format string. This is probably causing `scanf` to fail. You should always check the return value of `scanf`, to see if the function was successful or not.
3. The `\n` in the format string will cause `scanf` to continue reading whitespace, until it finds a non-whitespace character. This means that you must press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key at least twice and must provide additional input. This is probably not what you want.

Therefore, you should change that line to the following:

`scanf("%lf", &income);`

Also, the statements

`if (0 < income <= 24000)`

and

`else if (24000 < income <= 58000)`

are wrong.

They should probably be

`if (0 < income && income <= 24000)`

and:

`else if ( 24000 < income && income <= 58000 )`

The reason they are wrong is the following:

According to [the rules on operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression

`24000 < income <= 58000`

is equivalent to:

`(24000 < income) <= 58000`

This means that this expression is equivalent to either

`0 <= 58000`

or

`1 <= 58000`

depending on whether `(24000 < income)` evaluates to true (`1`) or false (`0`).

In both cases, the entire expression will evaluate to true, because `58000` is larger than both `0` and `1`.

That is why writing

`if (0 < income <= 24000)`

and

`else if (24000 < income <= 58000)`

does not make sense, because these statements are equivalent to writing

`if ( 1 )`

and:

`else if ( 1 )`

Comment: Dear Andrea,
thank you so much for your feedback. i was reviewing the code and found noticed the ones you pointed out and fixed it, but it still will not calculate the taxes owed part. after i input the filing status and the income amount, it just give me

"Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 4.239 s
Press any key to continue."

do you have any idea why it doesn't print the taxes owed are with the amount?

Comment: @NewB123: On Microsoft Windows, the code `0xC0000005` usually stands for "access violation", which is the Windows equivalent of a "segmentation fault". This means that you are reading or writing from memory which you do not have permission to touch. Please show me your latest code by adding it to the bottom of the question, without overwriting your original question.

Comment: @NewB123: You have now invalidated my answer, by overwriting your original question. Please restore your original question and add your latest code to the bottom of the question.

Comment: sorry Andrea, im still new at this website/forum and just very new to coding didn't know, i restored the original question. and added my latest code

Comment: @NewB123: In my answer, I recommended that you change `scanf("%.2lf\n", income);` to `scanf("%lf", &income);`, but the `&` (address-of) is still missing in your latest code.

Comment: i just added the revised one, once again, sorry. i live in USA and it's 2:41am here so my mind is a bit tired and i missed that, thank you for pointing out again.  again, much appreciate your help